# Configuring Single Sign-on with OpenID Connect

Tags: java, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Following steps as described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+Single+Sign-on+with+OpenID+Connect#UMDBFormat):

I think I have configured steps 1-4  but starting up my `IS V5.7` for step 5 falls apart.

Initial problems like an incorrectly formatted `user-mgt.xml` and missing `jdbc jar` file I was able to solve but I don't have a clue how the remaining problems are to be addressed.

Configuration complexity is huge in this environment. 
I run `Windows 10`, `Java 1.8 IS 5.7 and Apim 2.6 & MySQL 5.7`

Don't seem to be able to attach files.
At the end of this post I will list the server log starting from where things go wrong.
if in need for further info please let me know

Anyone any suggestions?

Thanks Peter

### server.log

```
[2020-01-30 08:23:44,761]  INFO {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.app.mgt.TomcatJaggeryWebappsDeployer} -  Deployed webapp: StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/portal].File[C:\data\WSO2ID~1.0\bin\..\repository\deployment\server\jaggeryapps\portal]
[2020-01-30 08:23:44,799]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpTransportListener} -  HTTP port        : 9763
[2020-01-30 08:23:44,799]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener} -  HTTPS port       : 9443
[2020-01-30 08:23:49,031] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantEagerLoader} -  Could not load valid tenant domains
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error in getting the tenants.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getAllTenants(JDBCTenantManager.java:394)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getAllTenants(JDBCTenantManager.java:54)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantEagerLoader.getValidTenantDomains(TenantEagerLoader.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantEagerLoader.initializeEagerLoadingTenants(TenantEagerLoader.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.completeInitialization(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.serviceChanged(StartupFinalizerServiceComponent.java:317)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.server.admin.internal.ServerAdminServiceComponent.activate(ServerAdminServiceComponent.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:906)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:831)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.util.DatabaseUtil.getDBConnection(DatabaseUtil.java:868)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getDBConnection(JDBCTenantManager.java:676)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager.getAllTenants(JDBCTenantManager.java:363)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:338)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:329)
    ... 62 more
[2020-01-30 08:23:49,153]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.healthcheck.api.core.internal.HealthMonitorServiceComponent} -  Carbon health monitoring service is activated..
[2020-01-30 08:23:54,459] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.util.CommonUtil} -  Could not set authorizations for the /_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.all-themes.
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error! Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1434)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.authorizeRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:511)
    at org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.realm.RegistryAuthorizationManager.authorizeRole(RegistryAuthorizationManager.java:161)
    at org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.util.CommonUtil.setAnonAuthorization(CommonUtil.java:211)
    at org.wso2.carbon.theme.mgt.util.ThemeUtil.loadResourceThemes(ThemeUtil.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.theme.mgt.internal.TenantThemeMgtServiceComponent.activate(TenantThemeMgtServiceComponent.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.callSecure(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1424)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager$2.run(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1427)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error! Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.addAuthorizationForRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1079)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.authorizeRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:527)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:906)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:831)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:730)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:200)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.getDBConnection(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1288)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.addAuthorizationForRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1000)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151)
    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:338)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:777)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:486)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeAuthenticationProvider.connect(NativeAuthenticationProvider.java:202)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.connect(NativeProtocol.java:1340)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:157)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectWithRetries(ConnectionImpl.java:850)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.writeBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.OutputRecord.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecordInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.ExportControlled.performTlsHandshake(ExportControlled.java:336)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.performTlsHandshake(StandardSocketFactory.java:188)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.performTlsHandshake(NativeSocketConnection.java:99)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.negotiateSSLConnection(NativeProtocol.java:329)
    ... 58 more
[2020-01-30 08:23:54,463] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.theme.mgt.internal.TenantThemeMgtServiceComponent} -  ******* Multitenancy Theme Config bundle failed activating ****
org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.exceptions.RegistryException: Could not set authorizations for the /_system/governance/repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.all-themes.
    at org.wso2.carbon.stratos.common.util.CommonUtil.setAnonAuthorization(CommonUtil.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.theme.mgt.util.ThemeUtil.loadResourceThemes(ThemeUtil.java:195)
    at org.wso2.carbon.theme.mgt.internal.TenantThemeMgtServiceComponent.activate(TenantThemeMgtServiceComponent.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:515)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.removePendingItem(CarbonServerManager.java:291)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.bundleChanged(PreAxis2ConfigItemListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
[2020-01-30 08:23:54,945]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://localhost:9443/carbon/
```

Comment: "Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error! Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up." , Seems like an issue with your connection. Can you check whether Identity Server can access the DB connection without any issue.  Or whether you chave given enough privileges to access the DBs by the user configured in master-datasource.xml file.

Comment: a telnet to localhost 3306 seems to indicate that the MySQL database is there.
I have executed the script provided with the installation without problems.
I have given it the root user and its password 
Grants in the  in the database   are as follows: 

>show grants for 'root'@'localhost';
Grants for root@localhost
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION

Comment: please note that priviliges command output lists asterisk.asterisk which seems to be gone in the previous comment output

Comment: not ruling out firewall settings perhaps ?
mysqld in windows defender firewall only had public checked. But checking Private as well and restarting the server didn't make a difference.

Comment: As per logs, the driver class name seems to be **com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver** which is the driver class for **MySQL 8.0**. What is the driver class jar you have added in dropins?

Comment: I have added mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar to the <IS-HOME>\repository\components\lib directory
if I need an older version please advice

Comment: As a result of which?  I see a mysql_connector_java_8.0.19_1.0.0.jar file in <IS-HOME>\repository\components\dropins

Comment: Can you download and add MySQL 5.x jar to lib folder and try? This link may help you - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

Comment: You have to use the 5.x MySQL driver jar and in master-datasources.xml, you need to add driver class as **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver**

Comment: Hi Vithursa,  I will try and let you know.  Obviously I checked the jar version against my sql 5.7 instance.  However the (Oracle) docs seemed to suggest that even for 5.7 you needed to upgrade/use connector/j v8?

Comment: Hi ,  I dropped the MySQL_connector_java_5.1.48_bin.jar in the <IS-HOME>  tree. 
I have a definition in master-datasources.xml that refers to com.mysql.jdbc.Driver as copied in from the example on the web site.  I don't see a definition of the driver class itself anywhere else but perhaps this is impliciet? 
Result is the same - it doesn't connect to the database

Comment: the "communications link failure" seemed to indicate that there is an ssl handshake problem. I configured "useSSL=false" in IS and then it works. Assuming a default MySQL server installation configures for the ssl protocol, the description of the configuration in the ws02 docs (referenced in the main post) should state more clearly that you MUST switch this off in IS OR describe (additionally) how to enable it on IS side.  My setup is a local desktop for testing so I can do without SSL but for production it needs to be addressed in due time

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

As per the above stack trace, DB connection has failed.

DB connection can be failed due to one or more of the following causes:

1.IP address or hostname in JDBC URL is wrong.
2. Hostname in JDBC URL is not recognized by local DNS server.
3. Port number is missing or wrong in JDBC URL.
4. DB server is down.
5. DB server doesn't accept TCP/IP connections.
6. DB server has run out of connections.
7. Something in between Java and DB is blocking connections, e.g. a firewall or proxy.
8. An issue with Jdbc driver like incompatible version or wrongly-placed it
9. Miss some parameters in JDBC connection Url like useSSL

Our Recommendations

To resolve any of the above mentioned issues, you can follow below given instructions.

1. Verify and test them with ping.
2. Refresh DNS or use IP address in JDBC URL instead.
3. Verify it based on my.cnf of MySQL DB.
4. Start the DB.
5. Verify if mysqld is started without the --skip-networking option.
6. Disable firewall and/or configure firewall/proxy to allow/forward the port.
7. Putting correct Jdbc driver to correct place
8. Pass the required parametres to establish the connection

Comment: Hi Nadee, thank you for your efforts and suggestions. As indicated in my last comment under my original post I found out that the problem is the ssl handshake that the MySQL server wants to engage in (is configured with (by default)?) and wasn't supported initially by IS. Since you seem to represent ws02 I hope you can look at improving the case description as mentioned. I would be interested to know anyway what I need to configure on the IS side when I DO want ssl between IS and the MySQL database.